# How can I add a sentinel While Loop and a For Loop

Tags: python, logic

```
def mult(num1, num2, num3):
    return num1,num1 * num2,num1 * num3

num1 = int(input("Please enter a number to be doubled and tripled: "))
num2 = 2
num3 = 3
myAnswer = (mult(num1, num2, num3))
print("Your number doubled and tripled",(myAnswer))
input("Press ENTER to continue.")
```

This is what I have so far. How can I edit my code to make the output look like this, if the user entered 3, for example:

```
1  2  3

2  4  6

3  6  9
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got what you're looking for (please clarify in the comments) but I think it's this:

```
def mult(num1, num2, num3):
    return num1,num1 * num2,num1 * num3

num1 = int(input("Please enter a number to be doubled and tripled: "))
num2 = 2
num3 = 3
for num in range(num1):
    num = num + 1     #Because range will give [0, 1, 2, ... , num-1]
    print("Your number doubled and tripled", mult(num, num2, num3))
input("Press ENTER to continue.")
```

A simpler way would be:

```
def mult(num):
    print("Your number doubled and tripled")
    for i in range(num):
        i = i + 1
        print(i, i*2, i*3)

num = int(input("Please enter a number to be doubled and tripled: "))
mult(num)
input("Press ENTER to continue.")
```

Comment: If you  think so, please accept my answer (the tick button at the top left corner of my answer)